cart button not open the cart react JS
Hello I have a problem when I press on the basket it does not open here are the different codes.
The transition works but the button does not work it does not want to display the cart.
Don't hesitate to ask me questions
I've looked at a lot of tutorials and forums but I can't find anything if someone can help me.
App.js :
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import WatchCustomizer from './components/WatchCustomizer';
import ProductList from './components/ProductList';
import Cart from './components/Cart';

function App() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    const existingItem = cartItems.find(cartItem => cartItem.id === item.id);
    if (existingItem) {
      setCartItems(cartItems.map(cartItem =>
        cartItem.id === item.id ? { ...existingItem, quantity: existingItem.quantity + 1 } : cartItem
      ));
    } else {
      setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...item, quantity: 1 }]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar cartCount={cartItems.length} setShowCart={setShowCart} />
        <Cart 
          cartItems={cartItems} 
          setCartItems={setCartItems} 
          setShowCart={setShowCart} 
          className={showCart ? 'show' : ''}
        />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Bienvenue sur notre site de montres. Sélectionnez une option dans le menu.</h1>} />
          <Route path="/customizer" element={<WatchCustomizer addToCart={addToCart} />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<ProductList addToCart={addToCart} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

Cart.js :
import './css/Cart.css';

function Cart({ cartItems, setCartItems, setShowCart }) {
    const handleQuantityChange = (item, delta) => {
      const updatedItems = cartItems.map(cartItem =>
        cartItem.id === item.id
          ? { ...cartItem, quantity: Math.max(cartItem.quantity + delta, 1) }
          : cartItem
      );
      setCartItems(updatedItems);
    };
  
    const handleRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
      setCartItems(cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== itemId));
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="cart-container">
        <div className="cart-overlay" onClick={() => setShowCart(false)} />
        <div className="cart">
          <h2>Mon Panier</h2>
          {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
            <p>Votre panier est vide.</p>
          ) : (
            cartItems.map(item => (
              <div key={item.id} className="cart-item">
                <span>{item.name}</span>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={() => handleQuantityChange(item, -1)}>-</button>
                  <span>{item.quantity}</span>
                  <button onClick={() => handleQuantityChange(item, 1)}>+</button>
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(item.id)}>Supprimer</button>
              </div>
            ))
          )}
          <button onClick={() => {/* logique de checkout */}}>Checkout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default Cart;

NavBar.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = ({ cartCount, setShowCart }) => {
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/customizer">Personnalise ta montre</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/products">Nos Montres</Link></li>
          <li className="cart-icon" onClick={() => setShowCart(true)}>
             <span className="cart-count">{cartCount}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  };

export default NavBar;

Cart.css :
.cart {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -400px; /* Position initiale hors de l'écran */
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: -2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: right 0.3s ease; /* Animation */
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 1000; /* Assurez-vous que le panier est au-dessus des autres éléments */
  }
  
  .cart.show {
    right: 0; /* Montre le panier */
  }
  
  .close-cart {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  
  .cart-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  
  .checkout-button {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #61dafb;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


I think you should try to set className="show" to the first div within the Cart component and not to the component itself as you do it now.

Why are you using className as prop? className is not a reserved word but it is a special prop in React. Although you can use it to pass prop, you might get confused later, if your codebase gets bigger.
You are passing className to cart but not calling the prop in Cart component.
Here, I have an example of what you should be doing.
Display Cart
or, this is what you should be doing.
App.js


import "./styles.css";

import { useState } from "react";
import Cart from "./Cart";

export default function App() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <p>This is shop route</p>
      <button onClick={() => setShowCart(!showCart)}>
        Toggle show cart state
      </button>
      <Cart
        className={showCart ? "show" : ""} //dont do this
        showCart={showCart} //do this
      />
    </>
  );
}



Cart.js


import "./styles.css";

export default function Cart({ showCart }) {
  return <p className={showCart ? "cart show" : "cart"}>Cart</p>;
}



styles.css


//This is your css

.cart {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -400px; /* Position initiale hors de l'écran */
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: right 0.3s ease; /* Animation */
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 1000; /* Assurez-vous que le panier est au-dessus des autres éléments */
}

.cart.show {
  right: 0; /* Montre le panier */
}

.close-cart {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}



If you want to view demo, click here or visit https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/64n67t
Hope this helps.
